# DQL - similar function to the mysql LAST

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

In mysql, there is a function last that returns the last found value. I would like to get the same with DQL in a symfony project. Is this somehow possible.

ie: I have 10 items in my table. With my where, I am getting 5 of them, but I would like to get the last of those 5:

```
$lastPaperQB = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'p' )
    ->select('LAST(p)')
    ->where("p.conference_id = :c AND p.section_id = :s")
    ->setParameter('c', $conference_id)
    ->setParameter('s', $section_id);
```

But the problem is that the LAST does not exist in DQL:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'LAST'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such function in mysql. It's from ms access. You want to use `order by` together with `limit`. Without `order by` you are not guaranteed to get the same row from the 5 rows.

Comment: Or simply use the MAX(p), so I will get the biggest one.

Comment: Also possible, if you are not interested in the row but only the maximum value.